# <select> Dropdown list events on iOS 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ios11

I have encountered a problem when I run my app built with ionic1 on iOS 11.
The problem is that the `<select>` tag dropdown list appears in a native window and none of the event are fired after the user has selected (more like highlighted) a different option. There is no way to properly "confirm" a change of selection in that list and that's all the problem.

ng-change, ng-blur and ng-focus doesn't seem to work at all.

Here is a snippet of the code I am talking about:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.place for item in placesOfWork"
ng-model="currentPlaceOfWork.value"
ng-change="getChangingWorkPlace(currentPlaceOfWork)"
class="select-place-of-work">
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

**Update!** 
The problem has somehow been solved, I was missing the "Done" buton on the native iOS select dropdown list. Probably an issue with cordova plugins.

Comment: can you try in this way ? 
<select ng-model="currentPlaceOfWork.value" ng-change="getChangingWorkPlace(currentPlaceOfWork)" class="select-place-of-work">
 <option ng-repeat="item in placesOfWork" ng-value="item.place">{{item}}</option>
</select>

Comment: Thank you FarukT

Answer (score 0):

did you try with `$scope.$watch` ?

you can make a function like this

```
$scope.$watch("currentPlaceOfWork.value",function(nextValue,oldValue){
if(nextValue != null && nextValue != oldValue){
   //call your function
   $scope.getChangingWorkPlace(nextValue);
 }
});
```